# Drupal Views Module is stuck on my custom theme

Tags: drupal, view, settings, default

So I was going through the settings in the Views Module and hit a checkbox and clicked save. This unfortunately transformed the entire Views UI into my custom theme's homepage. And trying to go into settings does not allow me to see anything except my custom homepage. I've tried uninstalling the module and deleting EVERYTHING but nothing seems to work. How can I manually undo check whatever box I had checked.

Answer (score 0):

it needs a little bit of debugging.

- go into views source code, look for .module files and search for
  hook_menu() implementation
- find there an URL where you have checked that checkbox
- go into page callback function
- check for submit callback function and go to that function
- look for update queries or variables settings, anything that have a machine name of your checkbox, look for the mysql table and field
- go into database and update that field to your needs

you can also use a fresh drupal install to perform this, it will be easier to just copy the value from one database field into another

Comment: I feel like you misunderstood my question. I actually hit a checkbox that was in the views UI in the settings. It was something along the lines of "Use custom theme for Views?."

Comment: please upload a screenshot with url where it happens